# Boost error "Structure has no member named 'serialize' " though the structure has serialize

Tags: boost, boost-serialization

Below are the structures and a class i have designed and the ultimate goal is to write values to an xml using boost serialization
When i compile the code below i get a compile time error (The error is huge and i just pasted the last line of it which perhaps talks about the issue)

> /boost_1_49_0/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118: error: 'class std::map, std::allocator >, std::map, std::allocator >, std::map, std::allocator >, IdInfo, std::less, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator >, IdInfo> > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator >, std::map, std::allocator >, IdInfo, std::less, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator >, IdInfo> > > > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator >, std::map, std::allocator >, std::map, std::allocator >, IdInfo, std::less, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator >, IdInfo> > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator >, std::map, std::allocator >, IdInfo, std::less, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator >, IdInfo> > > > > > > > >' has no member named 'serialize'
>   make: *** [READER.exe] Error 1

The AssetReaderInfo clkass below actually has a member serialize but the error contradicts it.

i have defined serialization in all the classes but its failing to compile
Also, I havent specfied the main cpp code as i thought it adds to confusion

Would you please suggest what went wrong ?

```
struct IdInfo
{
    std::string m_milePost;
    std::string m_cellModemAlertExclusionList;

    public:
    IdInfo():m_milePost("milepost"),m_cellModemAlertExclusionList("dummyval"){};

    template<class archive>
    void serialize(archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
         ar & make_nvp("values", m_milePost);
         ar & make_nvp("values", m_cellModemAlertExclusionList);
    }
};

class myReader {
 public:

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
   // Asset ID list
   typedef std::map< std::string,IdInfo > myMap;
   typedef std::map< std::string > mySet;
   struct ReaderInfo
   {
         mySet m_aSList;
         myMap m_pList;
         myMap m_eList;
         // WIU/BS type
         std::string m_Type;
         std::string m_topic;
         std::string m_lastSavedMsg;
         template <class archive>
         void serialize(archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
         {
           using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
            ar & make_nvp("values", m_topic);
            ar & make_nvp("values", m_Type);
            ar & make_nvp("values", m_eList);
            ar & make_nvp("values", m_pList);
         }

   };
    typedef std::map< std::string, ReaderInfo > GroupDataMap;
    GroupDataMap    m_GroupDataMap;

    template<class archive>
    void serialize(archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
        ar & make_nvp("Group", m_GroupDataMap);
    } 
}

int main()
{
   myReader Reader;
   boost::archive::xml_oarchive xml(ofs);
   xml << boost::serialization::make_nvp("Connections", Reader);
}
```

Solution:

> It turns out that i should include /boost/serialization/map.hpp as iam using a std::map

Thanks for the Help

Comment: Either delete or self-answer. This way it's clear that the question is no longer requiring attention

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that i should include `/boost/serialization/map`.hpp as iam using a `std::map`

> #include /boost/serialization/map.hpp